# git merge <branch> doesn't reflect in the network graph of github, why is that?

Tags: git, github

`git merge <branch>` doesn't reflect in the network graph of github, why is that?

```bash
git branch feature
#lets assume I made some changes, added them to staging area and committed to local repo
git push -u origin feature
git checkout main
git merge feature
git push -u origin main
```

Doing this doesn't show any merging in the Network graph of Github?

Where merging the branch with pull request shows merging in the Network graph of Github!

EDIT:
With pull request

[image: pic1]

With merge command

[image: pic2]

Comment: May you share a screenshot of the network graph?

Comment: What message do you get in the CLI when you run "git push -u origin main"? Or when you run "git merge feature".

Comment: ```Updating af28fa5..2c8de9d
Fast-forward
 chapter6.txt | 0
 chapter7.txt | 0
 2 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 chapter6.txt
 create mode 100644 chapter7.txt```

Comment: It might be that the merge became a "fast forward merge". If `main` is still a direct ancestor of `feature` then instead of making a merge commit it will simply move the `main` pointer. I think you can set some settings if you don't want git to do `fast-forward` merges when it is possible.

Comment: Always troubleshoot what Git is doing locally before suspecting something else (in this case it was just a fast-forward, as explained).